# Ubuntu 22.04 crashed and is now asking for a fresh install when restarted

Tags: 22.04, live-usb, gparted

I’m running Ubuntu 22.04 on a 2008 MBP the SSD is brand new but has crashed after MPV (video player) was repeatedly opened and closed, now every time I restart I’m sent to system configuration and it’s asking for a fresh restart, does anyone know what is happening and how it can be fixed? I tried gparted but I can’t even check the desk I know the files are still on there because I’m able to look inside the drive but I can’t fix it.

This is what boots up not my login screen:

[image: Screen photo 1]

I checked my folders everything’s there

[image: Screen photo 2]

Gparted won’t allow me to check:

[image: Screen photo 3]

I was advised to download smartctl but my live usb that I’m using doesn’t have Wi-Fi drivers installed on it.

Comment: That's weird, it's showing the OEM setup screen. You didn't happen to install Ubuntu using the "OEM install (for manufacturers)" option, did you?

Comment: nope did a regular  install 2 weeks ago this is the first time ever ever came across this issue.

Comment: Wait I’m just now remembering something very important Important this file showed up on my Desktop for some reason this morning https://ibb.co/ZxYb7K3

Comment: For some reason I clicked it, I have zero clue how this file showed up on my desktop but I assumed that I had to type in my password when it requested it to get rid of it.

Comment: Yeah that looks like you did an OEM install on accident. This gives you an OEM user account that allows you to modify the system so that you can add software and drivers and stuff like that, then you double-click that icon, shutdown the computer, then package it and ship it to the person who will actually use it. They then boot the system and the setup screen you're looking at shows up.

Comment: If you have important data on this system, ***DO NOT*** go through the setup procedure. Backup everything and reinstall from scratch (using the normal "Install Ubuntu" bootup option, not the "OEM installation" option).

Comment: Ok yeah you guys are right also I was told that it’s a possibility that my new SSD is just corrupted which is why the file popped up on my desktop all of a sudden I’ve checked my screen shots and it was never there until this morning thanks for the advice guys. ✌️

Answer (score 1):

This looks like somehow you accidentally did an OEM installation of Ubuntu and then used the OEM user account as a normal user account. If you saved important data on this system, ***DO NOT*** go through the setup wizard you're seeing at bootup, as this will probably wipe all your data. The best solution at this point is to boot from a live ISO of Ubuntu, back up all your data to an external drive, and then install Ubuntu from scratch (using the "Install Ubuntu" option at bootup, not the "OEM install (for manufacturers)" option). You will need at least two external drives to do this - one to flash the live ISO to and boot from, and the other to store your data. **Do not** attempt to use the same flash drive to boot from and to store your data, as doing this could result in your data being lost when you shut the computer down.

If you're wondering why on earth this weird setup option exists, here's why.

The OEM installation option is designed to allow computer manufacturers to ship systems with Ubuntu preinstalled. Basically, if you are selling computers with Ubuntu, you can set them up using the OEM installation option, log into the OEM user, install any additional software and drivers you want to ship with the system, then run the "Prepare for shipping to end user" shortcut and shutdown the computer. At that point you would package the computer up and sell it. It would never be turned on by you again after running that shortcut.

When the end user gets the system, they boot it and then get the setup screen you're looking at. This allows them to set up the system for themselves.

This works out great if you're selling a computer, but not so great if you're installing it for your own use. From my research, I believe the OEM user is supposed to be deleted automatically during the setup procedure, and if that user has any important data in it, it will probably be lost.